# Replicating Homestead Environment on Ubuntu 14.04.5

Tags: homestead

I am currently working on a laravel project on my MAC using homestead environment. Am i able to replicate a homestead environment on Ubuntu 14.04.5?

Comment: If yes, how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replicate the homestead environment you need to install this softwares as listed in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/homestead):

- Git
- PHP 7.1
- Nginx
- MySQL
- MariaDB
- Sqlite3
- Postgres
- Composer
- Node (With Yarn, Bower, Grunt, and Gulp)
- Redis
- Memcached
- Beanstalkd
- Mailhog
- ngrok

Probably you do not need all of them so remove what you do not use.
To install each software you can try so search in the `apt` repository and search for a guide con configure each of them.

For a LEMP stack you can try this: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-in-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: Thank you so much, i will get on it and revert back!

Answer (score 0):

Homestead uses a script called settler that it uses to provision the environment you use in Homestead, the script can be found here:

https://github.com/laravel/settler/blob/master/scripts/provision.sh